# Will this process affect database availability?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, backup

http://rockingtechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/oracle-backup-and-restore-code-in-cnet.html

As per the proposed code in the above article, more specifically:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "C:/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/BIN/exp.exe";
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

How can I expect the database to be affected with regards to interruption of CRUD operations from elsewhere once calling Process.Start(psi) and, hence, executing exp.exe?

Using Oracle's exp.exe process - will the sessions of all users currently writing to the db in question be killed, for example? I'd imagine (or at least hope) not, but I haven't been able to find documentation to confirm this.

Comment: Downvotes without accompanying critique are pretty useless to me. I've done my best to keep this question specific, on topic, and I've already mentioned my 'what have you tried' in the form of looking for documentation.

Comment: The close voters think this is NARQ or off topic.  Any certainly it is not a programming question.

Comment: "it is not a programming question" - it certainly is. You can see code there that you can assume I will be programming, I'm asking about what effect I can expect this programming to have. Completely programming related.

Comment: No, you're asking about the impact of an Oracle database utility on your users.  How you invoke the utility is irrelevant.

Comment: My downvote is because you ask about what performance costs that might be connected to doing this but you don't post any information on the metrics you ran to determine this is even an issue.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXP and IMP are not proper backup and recover tools.  They are intended for exchanging data and data structures between Oracle databases.  This is also true for their replacement, Data Pump (EXPDP and IMPDP).

Export unloads to a file so it won't affect any users on the system.  However if you want a consistent set of data you need to use the CONSISTENT=Y parameter if there are any other users connecting to the system .

Interestingly Data Pump does not have a CONSISTENT parameter.  It unloads tables (or table partitions) as single transactions but the only way to guarantee consistency across all database objects is to use the FLASHBACK_SCN parameter (or kick all your users off the system).

---

> "It is all in aid of DR."

As a DR solution this will work, with the following provisos.

1. The users will lose all data since the last export (obvious)
2. You will need to ensure the export is consistent across all objects
3. Imports take time.  A lot of time if you have many tables or a lot of data.  Plus indexes, etc

Also remember to export the statistics as well as the data.

Comment: Is it RMAN you would recommend as the most appropriate backup tool? I naturally landed at the solution of .net code as it has been requested that a .net app be developed that provides a UI that allows the user to configure scheduled migrations of the db structure and it's contents off-site.

Comment: The question is, how will they want to use the migrated data subsequently?  IMNP or IMPDP work by (optionally) blatting the tables and then inserting the data from the dump files.  They can't handle primary key clashes, changes to tables structures, etc.  They can't be used to recover data from or to a point in time.   RMAN has much more flexibility in how data can be restored.

Comment: The app would also take care of the restoration, it would invoke impdp into the 'off-site' location in the same 'breath'.

Comment: It is all in aid of DR. BTW - I'm not going to be ignorant about this, if RMAN is the better, more fitting solution I will look into it further. I want the best for the solution, I'm simply just proposing my initial thought process.

Comment: You've been more than helpful mate, really appreciated. Duly noted the issue of this not being a programming question for the future too. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You're really asking what effects the (old) [Oracle export tool (`exp`)](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ) has on the database. It's a logical backup so you can think of the effects generally the same way you would think of running multiple `SELECT` queries against your database. That is, other sessions don't get killed but normal locking mechanisms may prevent them from accessing data until `exp` is done with it and this could, potentially, lead to timeouts.

Comment: Brilliant. Already, just from reading your answer I have discovered expdp since you described exp as old, and I have a better insight into the way it works. A LOT more helpful than the close and down votes given without explanation. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`EXP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#SUTIL3634) is the original export utility. It is discontinued and not supported in the most recent version (11g).

You can use [`EXPDP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007466) instead, although the export files are written on the server instead of the client machine.

Both utilities issue standard `SELECT` commands to the database, and since readers don't interfere with concurrency in Oracle (writer don't block readers, readers don't block readers), this will not block your other DB operations.

Since it issues statements however, it may increase the resource usage, especially IO, which could impact performance for concurrent activity.

Whatever tool you use, you should spend some time learning about the options (also since you may want to use it as a logical copy, make sure you test the respective import tools [IMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#BABBHCIE) and [IMPDP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#i1007653)). Also a word of warning: these tools are not backup tools. You should not rely on them for backup.

Comment: As per my comment on Alkini, very helpful. Thanks very much mate.